# Verbatim overruns text block

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

The problem when I export the document to PDF there is some text at the end of the lines does not appear to the print page. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{verbatim}
//Add staff.php
<link href="../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<form action="savestaff.php" method="post">
<center><h4><i class="icon-plus-sign icon-large"></i> Register Staffs</h4></center>
<hr>
<div id="ac">
<span>Staff Id : </span><input type="text" style="width:265px; height:30px;" 
name="Staffid" 
placeholder="Staff Id" 
Required/><br>
<span>First Name : </span><input type="text" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="Fname" placeholder="Fname" Required/><br>
<span>Last Name : </span><input type="text" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="Lname" placeholder="Lname" Required/><br>
<span>Gender : </span><input type="text" style="width:265px; height:60px;" name="Gender" placeholder="Gender" Required/><br>
<span>Date of birth : </span><input type="text" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="DateOfBirth" placeholder="DateOfBirth" Required/><br>
<span>Phone Number : </span><input type="text" style="height:60px; width:265px;" name="PhNo" placeholder="PhNo" Required/><br>
<span>Email: </span><input type="date" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="Email" placeholder="Email" Required/><br>
<span>Home Address : </span><input type="date" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="HomeAddress" placeholder="HomeAddress" Required/><br>
<span>Staff Position : </span><input type="date" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="position" placeholder="position" Required/><br>
<span>Staff Password : </span><input type="date" style="width:265px; height:30px;" name="password" placeholder="password" Required/><br>
<div style="float:right; margin-right:10px;">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-large" style="width:267px;"><i class="icon icon-save icon-large"></i> Save</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The `verbatim` macro takes its line-feed from the input text, not the document margin (that is why it is `verbatim`).  You could break up the long lines manually, or you could shrink the size of the verbatim listing easily enough.  There may be some other similar environments (`listings` comes to mind) that may be able to automate the newline.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using the `listings` package for this; it's considerably more flexible. For example, you can specify `\lstset{breaklines=true}` in the preamble to prevent lines from overrunning the margins.

Here's a basic way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    % specifies that lines shouldn't overrun the margin
    breaklines=true
    % specified that, if possible, lines should be broken at whitespace
    breakatwhitespace=true 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
//Add staff.php
<link href="../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<form action="savestaff.php" method="post">

... rest of HTML snippet ... 

</div>
</div>
</form>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here's what it will look like.

[image]

You can also make `listings` syntax-highlight this code for you, which might be useful. For example, suppose we change the preamble to this:

```
\documentclass[preview, margin=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    identifierstyle=\color[HTML]{CF000F},
    keywordstyle=\color[HTML]{0E723C},
    language=HTML,
    stringstyle=\color[HTML]{1A337B},
    showstringspaces=false
}
```

Then, you get colored ouput:
[image]

There's lots more to explore; I found [Wikibooks' article on `listings`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) to be a good introductory guide.